# Oracle - How do I add a column and set the datatype

Tags: oracle, types

I am not having much luck with this.  I am creating a new table and adding columns with a default value - the table is defaulting column datatypes to CHAR 7, but this last column needs to be CHAR 30.

So far, I've only been able to modify the table after creation, but there must a way to do this all in one step.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 parallel 8 NOLOGGING AS
SELECT
  t2.1,
  t2.2,
  t2.3,
  'N' AS Store,
  'N' AS Address,
  'N' AS Owner,
  'N' AS User,
  'N' AS Business,
  'Unknown' AS Source
FROM t2
```

The final column (Source) values are longer than 7 characters, but all other values are Y/N.  My first thought was to do 'Unknown' AS Source (char 30), but I continue to get ORA-00923

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it needs to be a CHAR(30) you should ensure it is. Padding it with spaces is not necessarily the correct way to go; it's better to tell the database that's what you want it to be using the [CAST()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) function, which converts between data-types:

```
cast('Unknown' as char(30)) as source
```

Comment: It's not quite the same @Sebas, but yes; never once had the need to use a CHAR field...

Comment: This is the correct answer but using CHAR is a bad solution.  The constant need to CAST() or RPAD() is a serious drain for developers and users.